# Compile error after migrating from node-sass to dart-sass

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, create-react-app, node-sass

I have recently started working on a legacy project and trying to "revive" it, without actually rewriting the whole thing.

Project is CRA, Node version 14.16.0

I updated from node-sass to dart-sass (1.62.1) and I keep getting this error on compile

[image: Screenshot 1]

Once I replace all `@import` with `@use` the error changes to this one

[image: Screenshot 2]

I've spent a good few hours on it but haven't been able to pinpoint the issue yet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

P.S. I've tried updating Webpack, re-installing dart-sass, re-installing sass-loader and css-loader. I've edited the App. scss file to no result, but if I just comment the whole file, the error disappears ‍♀️

Comment: Without the source code (or a minimal example with the error represented), I can't pinpoint the exact issue, but I do see you could be using `@import` in some places. `@import` is deprecated and could lead to errors cropping up. Did you also check to make sure you didn't accidentally edit some parts of the file which you didn't mean to? I only say that because I've done it too many times to count.